# Edit words in Zapier

Tags: javascript, zapier

Im trying to reverse words in Zapier. For example "word"-->"drow".

I already looked for an app which I can connect with Zapier, however I didn't found something. Maybe someone else knows something?

From my understanding, this can be also done by Code (Javascript or Python). Due to the fact that I have not really knowledge about coding and the app code by Zapier.

I tried this already, but it looks like that I'm making mistakes. Here is an example picture I tried.
[zapier test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S5Ll.png)

And the code:

```
var cname1 = inputData.cname1.substring();
reverseString('cname1');
function reverseString(str) {
 return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Can anyone help me with this topic?

---

*editor note*: after editing, Stackoverflow wouldn't let me re-save the original title: `Reverse words with Code by Zapier (Javascript/Python)`. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you need to return an object from Code by Zapier steps. Try this instead:

[image]

```js
const result = {};

Object.entries(inputData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value) {
    result[key] = value.split("").reverse().join("");
  } else {
    result[key] = 'EMPTY'; // so the key isn't lost; can remove this branch if you don't care
  }
});

return result
```

Comment: perfect that works! 
Do you have also an option to reverse multiple different attributes?
I have a total of 16 attributes to reverse. Of course, I can make 16 Zapier steps, but maybe there is a way to do this in one step? Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Additionally: I see that I get an error if my input is empty, what would be the if clause, to check if the input is not empty? To stop the reverse function and leave the reversed output empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should be reversing `cname1` variable and not 'cname1'(which is a string). So, your code should look like this:

```
var cname1 = inputData.cname1.substring();
reverseString(cname1); //remove the single quote otherwise you'll keep getting '1emanc' as the output no matter the value of cname1
function reverseString(str) {
 return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Unfortunately, I'm still trying to get an output. It keeps saying output is missing or syntax error.